# CSS body border using border image

Tags: css, border-image

I'm trying to create a body border pretty much exactly like the one in this example: it changes with the size of the window, but isn't affected by overflow.

https://css-tricks.com/examples/BodyBorder/

I can't find any information on how to do this with a `border-image` specifically, though. I've already got my `border-image` and its parameters all set up; I just can't figure out how to apply it to the body without being broken by overflow, all the snippets of code I've tried have either prevented scrolling entirely, such that overflow simply disappears above the page, or have failed to prevent the border from being interrupted by overflow.

It'd be nice if, to boot, there were some convenient way to have an area at the edge of the border where overflow text will fade.

Edit: adding style code. In response to one of the comments, I want to use an image specifically--a border image, not just color. I'm just wanting to adapt the border image style I already have working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
  white-space: ;
  color: white;
  word-break: break-all;
  font-weight: normal; text-shadow: .3vw .3vw #000000; font-size: 4vw; text-align: center; margin: 4vw;
}
body {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  border-image: url(border.png) 10% round;
  border-image-slice: 26 26 26 26;
  border-image-width: 3vw 3vw 3vw 3vw;
  border-image-outset: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  overflow: auto;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background: #70bg32;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#6363BD, #000052);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#6363BD, #000052);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#6363BD, #000052);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#6363BD, #000052);
    background: linear-gradient(#6363BD, #000052);
}

</style>
```

Comment: Do you want an image as border or just a color ? Add some HTML and CSS code, to better understand your question.

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you :)

Comment: I cleaned up and added all of my style code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a separate element for the effect, instead of styling `body` directly.

```css
:root {
  --page-border-width: 3vw;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #6363bd;
  padding: var(--page-border-width);
  margin: 0;
}

.page-border {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-image: url(https://placehold.it/10) 10% round;
  border-image-slice: 26 26 26 26;
  border-image-width: var(--page-border-width);
  border-image-outset: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-image-repeat: stretch stretch;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.page-border:after {
  content: '';
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .5));
  height: 20vh;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<div class="page-border"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you. you don't need to use `border-image` it can easily handle just with border and it's flexible too depends on the size of window. although using `overflow-x` is not a best way!

HTML codes:

```
<body>
  <div class="flex">
    <p>
       blablabla
    </p>
    <p>
       blablabla
    </p>
    <p>
       blablabla
    </p>
    <p>
       blablabla
    </p>
  </div>
```

Css code

```
body{
  background-color:#fff;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.flex{
  width: auto;
  height:auto;
  border:50px solid blue;
  display:block;
}
p{
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

you can find jsfidle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fkm8an5p/2/)

Comment: I may not have been entirely clear--I already have a border image, and I want to use that image, not a color, for the border. I'm using both that border image for the border, and a color gradient for the background.

I've actually gotten the border to properly fit the window by moving it to html instead of body, but unfortunately, scrolling breaks it.

Comment: you shouldn't add style to html tag. it is not standard and not clear. did you try `overflow-x:hidden;` ?

Comment: check the fiddle another time i fix it for you. if it works tell me to update the answer.

https://jsfiddle.net/cfLndb34/

Comment: I've just started doing everything as separate elements, seems to work a charm. :) I'll upload the final result if you're curious.